# jms and different versions of enums

Tags: java, serialization, enums, jms

My team provides a service to another team in the company via jms.  This involves an enum which is passed in to us as part of a larger object.  They will soon be changing the definition of the enum - however, I would like to change it first so i can have our service running in production a few days before the change.  The change will just involve adding another constant at the end.
Can I do this safely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Java Object Serialization Specification version 6.0](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6469) (emphasises are mine):

> The serialized form of an enum constant consists **solely of its name**; [...]. To serialize an enum constant, `ObjectOutputStream` writes the **value returned by the enum constant's `name` method**. To deserialize an enum constant, `ObjectInputStream` reads the constant name from the stream; the deserialized constant is then obtained by **calling the java.lang.Enum.valueOf method**, passing the constant's enum type along with the received constant name as arguments.

This means that:

- Adding new value to the `enum` *is* backward compatible when it comes to serialization
- Reordering existing `enum` values *is* backward compatible (in contrary to default JPA `enum` persistence strategy that uses `ordinal()`)
- Removing values from `enum` *is not* backward compatible in general, since the removed values might have already been used for serialization purposes
- Renaming `enum` values *is not* backward compatible (see above)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, your object containing the enum is sent as a part of an ObjectMessage. If this is the case, it used usual Java Serialization to encode and decode the enum object.

Serialization for enums works by name - i.e. in fact they are sending the name of the enum value (together with an identifier for its class). As long as the values actually sent are existent on the other receiving side, there should be no problem.

Of course, you have to make sure the meaning of the message doesn't change by your change.

Comment: And of course, Tomasz answers one minute before me, after half an hour nobody answers. (I first had to download the JMS specification for this to see if they are actually using Serialization here. They do, see section 3.11.)